# how can use start and count in the linkedin api?

Tags: api, linkedin-api

i am using linked api for profile search..
the api is ""http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,public-profile-url))?keywords=[" + txtsearch.Text + "]";"

but i get only 10 profiles at a time..
so how can i get all the profile related to that search.

with regards.
plz do reply

Answer (score 0):

Try http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,public-profile-url))?keywords=" + txtsearch.Text + "&count=25&start=25"

This is to fetch records from 25 till 49.
But anyway there are limitation of Linkedin API on number of records you can query.
This depends on you account type.

`txtsearch.Text` should be url-encoded.

Details are at http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1191.